# Is there a fix for Hadoop Yarn winutils error 0xc0000bb8 on Windows 10?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

Hadoop Yarn on Windows fails with 0xc0000bb8.

Error message

2021-03-12 21:25:55,192 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8031. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2021-03-12 21:25:58,057 ERROR util.SysInfoWindows: ExitCodeException exitCode=1:
PdhAddCounter \Network Interface(*)\Bytes Received/Sec failed with 0xc0000bb8.
Error in GetDiskAndNetwork. Err:1

```
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:1008)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:901)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:1213)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.SysInfoWindows.getSystemInfoInfoFromShell(SysInfoWindows.java:86)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.SysInfoWindows.refreshIfNeeded(SysInfoWindows.java:101)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.SysInfoWindows.getPhysicalMemorySize(SysInfoWindows.java:153)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.ResourceCalculatorPlugin.getPhysicalMemorySize(ResourceCalculatorPlugin.java:64)
```

This solution for this bug is published, but very difficult to implement.
I understand it is due to the windows language
is a winutils binaries that do not depend on windows language downloadale somewhere?
If not, can somone publish it